# c# entity framework dynamic tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a big table sharded into a smaller ones like table1, table2, ... Number of the tables is constantly changing. Also I have a bunch of IQueryable extensions written for the single table. What's the best practice to continue using my IQueryable extensions on a dynamic table name? Is it possible to do something as easy as this:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery< MyNewType>("select col1, col2, col3 from schema.table3");
```

And get IQueryable< MyNewType>?

Comment: No there is nothing such thing! For a generic type to work, everything has to be known at compile time. That's what generics are for; to give compiler support. Dynamics and generics contradict eachother.

Comment: A better question to ask yourself is why are you splitting a big table into smaller tables? There may be a good reason to do so, but it seems very odd to me. Perhaps you should be looking into data normalization.

Comment: At first I was doing so to parallelize clustered columnstore index build (I wanted to build with MAXDOP=1 to put data into the rowgroups with the same order as clustered key). I was doing it and later switching partitions to the main table. Partition count got too high, though and simple "select 1 * from table where partitionColumn = someVal" was taking a while.

Comment: "sharded into smaller tables" Do you mean that you are in the process of changing your database by splitting up tables into smaller tables, or are you creating queries where your return only some columns of the original tables?

Comment: They are identical tables, with the same columns